# Translation invariance of sets implies translation invariance of their generated sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, transfinite-recursion

If we have a collection of translation invariant sets  (i.e. if $A$ is in the collection, then $A+x$ is in it too) - assume we have some notion of addition (e.g in a vector space).

Is the generated sigma algebra also translation invariant?

I think it may be useful to use some kind of transfinite induction on the steps
of "generating" each set in the sigma algebra...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the generated $\sigma$-algebra $\langle \mathcal A\rangle $ is  translation invariant whenever the family of sets $\mathcal A$ is translation invariant. No transfinite induction is needed, if you recall that $\langle \mathcal A\rangle $ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\mathcal A$. Since $\langle \mathcal A\rangle +x$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and it contains $\mathcal A+x$, it follows that $$\langle \mathcal A+x\rangle \subseteq \langle \mathcal A\rangle +x$$ 
Applying the above to $\mathcal A= \mathcal A+x + (-x)$, we find that 
$$\langle \mathcal A \rangle  = \langle \mathcal A +x + (-x)\rangle \subseteq \langle \mathcal A+x\rangle +(-x)$$ 
and adding $x$ to both sides, $$\langle \mathcal A \rangle+x\subseteq \langle \mathcal A+x\rangle $$